# Representation of Sunni Islam

Tags: ummah

In non-Muslim countries, it is often desired to get a statement of a representative of the Muslim communities.

At present, there are usually a lot of communities, some of which are members of an organisation directly linked to a foreign state but no one is authorised to speak on behalf of all communities.

Is there a base in Islamic rulings on which Sunni Muslims could elect representatives for all communities or are there any Islamic rulings that forbid to do so?

Comment: Sunni Islam does not have official organization like the Catholics have with their church.

Comment: @TheZ I know that Sunni Islam does not have a hierarchy. A great part of Protestant Churches are by themselves autonomous but they elect representatives for political representation. My question is whether ruling in sunni Islam allows to elect such a representation.

Comment: Simply speaking each mosque usually has a representative who is the imam or maybe the director of the Islamic community who is in charge for  the mosque. And usually, but not exclusively, both are rather elected.